# Google Earth Engine returning white images

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, google-earth-engine-python-api

When I run the following code, a blank image is outputted.

```
coordinates = input()
geoCoordinates = json.loads(coordinates)
i_date = '1972-07-25'
f_date ='2022-12-31'
aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(geoCoordinates)
images = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T2").filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(i_date, f_date)
image = ee.Image(images.first()).clipToBoundsAndScale(aoi)
url = image.select("B4").getThumbURL()
disp.Image(url = url, width = 800)
```

[image]

Does anyone know why and how I can fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use `var` in order to introduce new variable into to GEE.
Second, you used `getThumbURL` without providing visualization parameters. These include `dimension`, `region`, and `format` of your image. Also you could use extra visualization parameters defined in `ee.data.getMapId`.
Third, I suggest using collection 2, Tier 1, [level 2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC09_C02_T1_L2) or [level 1](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC09_C02_T1_TOA) since they are Landsat data with the highest quality.

Also, you need to use `print` in order to see the link in your GEE console.
Your syntax is not reproducible. Here I provide the one that you can check on your machine.

Last point, there is a function `prepSrL8` I used for choosing Landsat scenes based on their quality (QA bands).

```
var i_date = '1972-07-25'
var f_date ='2022-12-31'

var aoi = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint([
[46.72759630878907,38.171211790897694],
[48.38103869160157,38.171211790897694],
[48.38103869160157,39.25559070083476],
[46.72759630878907,39.25559070083476],
[46.72759630878907,38.171211790897694]
  ]).bounds()
Map.centerObject(aoi, 8)
Map.addLayer(aoi, {}, 'Area of Interest')

var images = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2")
            .map(prepSrL8)
            .filterBounds(aoi)
            .filterDate(i_date, f_date)


var image = ee.Image(images.first()).clip(aoi); print (image)
Map.addLayer(image.select('SR_B4'),{min: 0, max: 0.25})

var gifParams = {
  'region': aoi.buffer(2000).bounds(),
  'dimensions': 1024,
  'bands': "SR_B4",
  'min': 0,
  'max': 0.25,
  'format': 'jpg'
};

var url = image.getThumbURL(gifParams)
print(url)


function prepSrL8(image) {
  // Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  var optical = image.select("SR_B.").multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  var thermal = image.select("ST_B.*").multiply(0.00341802).add(149)
      // Approximate 0 to 1 range.
      .subtract(270)//.divide(50)

  // Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
  return image.addBands(ee.Image.cat(optical, thermal), null, true)
    .updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense!!

Comment: My pleasure. If you get your answer, you could click on the tick bottom so others could be informed about this.